# Appstore upload error: The bundle uses a bundle name or display name associated with an Apple app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I want to upload a new version of my app to the appstore.
In the appstore I created the new version and the status is "Waiting For Upload". In the app bundle I changed the version form 1.1 to 1.1.1 .
When I upload the app I get the error "The bundle uses a bundle name or display name associated with an Apple app.".
I changed no other settings. The app was created with Xamarin Studio.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Error is self descriptive. I dont think that you need any other explaination

Comment: What is your bundle name? And what name is being displayed on the homescreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did almost the exact same thing a few weeks ago, in fact with the same "from" and "to" version number sequence. Try using 1.2 (or 1.2.0) instead of 1.1.1 - that seemed to work for me.